# How to constrain an overload on an `input_range` parameter to be on int-ranges only?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

If I overload `<<` for `input_range` like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, input_range auto&& data) {
  for(auto &e : data) { 
    os << e << ' '; 
  } 
  return os; 
}
```

to be able to output `array<int,7>`, `array<3,int>` as well as `vector<int>` I get an error for overload ambiguity when I output `"hello"`:

```
 // all ok:
 cout << array<int,4>{1,2,3,4} << endl;
 cout << array<int,7>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7} << endl;
 cout << array{1,2,3} << endl;
 cout << vector{1,2,3} << endl;
 // not ok, because ambiguous:
 cout << "hello";
```

see https://godbolt.org/z/1rdff5z4b

This gets confused with already existing `os& op<<(os&, const char*)`.

How can I specify my overload better to be only in `int`-ranges?

This here does not work with g++ 13.2 -- I think thats not the ways concepts can be used:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, input_range<int> auto&& data) { ... }
```